# Use subprocess to open terminal and run a command

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I want to open a new terminal window and run a simple command such as `echo hello world` or `python myscript.py`. However all I have achieved is opening a new terminal in which none of my commands are run. Below are some examples of things I have tried:

```
import subprocess
# -----------------------  
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "echo 'Hello World'"])
# -----------------------  
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "echo", "Hello", "World"])
# -----------------------  
x = subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal"])
x.communicate(["echo hello world"])
# -----------------------  
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
x = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal'], stdin=PIPE)
x.communicate("echo hello world")
# -----------------------  
def subprocess_cmd(cmd1,cmd2): # adapted from another Stack question
    p1 = Popen(cmd1.split(),stdout=PIPE)
    p2 = Popen(cmd2.split(),stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE)
    p1.stdout.close()
    return p2.communicate()[0]
subprocess_cmd('gnome-terminal','echo hello world') # Prnts in my IDE and opens blank gnome terminal
# -----------------------  
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "echo hello world"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `['gnome-terminal', '--', 'bash', '-c', '<my command>']` ? See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/974756/how-can-i-open-a-extra-console-and-run-a-program-in-it-with-one-command

Comment: Why you want to open terminal? if you want to execute cmds you can easily do it by using `exec()` without opening the terminal

Comment: Do yourself a really big favor and use a library (such as "sh").  There is a lot of quirckyness in subprocess : )   https://pypi.org/project/sh/

Comment: @NickODell this worked perfectly. If you want to leave it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
command = '<my command>'
subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'bash', '-c', command], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Here's the [manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal.1.en.html). [See also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974756/how-can-i-open-a-extra-console-and-run-a-program-in-it-with-one-command).